# How to handle concurrency only for a particular request path in google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, concurrency

Is there a way to process requests serially for only a particular request path with a dynamic path parameter?
Consider the path - get/x where x can be a dynamic path parameter. Is there a way in google app engine to process the requests serially for that particular path for a particular path parameter. If two requests come one after another for the path get/alpha, can these request be processed serially ?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how GAE handles scheduling/scaling and executing your java app you could enforce mutual exclusion or serializability at multiple levels.

**Application Level Distributed Lock**

One way is to enforce exclusion at your HTTP Application level.  This will allow you to synchronize `get/x` across multiple processes:

```
 @Override
  public void x(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

    // acquire lock from a lock service, a couple different options
    // to implement this
    DistributedLock lock = DistributedLock.Acquire()

    // do work because lock guarantees mutual exclusion


    // finally release the lock
    lock.Release()
  }
```

**DB Level Serializable Transaction**

If the operation to synchronize is a database operation you might be able to push it to the datalayer.  If your DB Supports [`SERIALIZABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-set-transaction.html) [transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52427050/594589) it can ensure that no two concurrent operations are modifying the same data at the same time.

**Process Level single Instance**

Another way you may be able to achieve this is to lean on guarantees that GAE provides.  If you package your endpoint as a separate application and deploy it as its own service with a single instance, google *MAY* (not sure of what guarantees they can provide you :p ) ensure that there is no more than a single instance of your service at a single time.  This would be the exact same code base but would be a separate configuration/application with only your endpoint exposed. This might be considered a “hack”.

Tricky parts here is during autoscaling or deploys, ideally there would be a way to set it so 2 instances are never up at a single time.

Comment: Hi, i cannot use the third option since my app runs with parallel instances. I cannot use DB level transactions since it requires changes in DB structure. May i get some info/documentation on the HTTP level distributed lock and the libraries that offer it

Comment: If i do use distributed lock on the method that processes the request, suppose i get two requests get/alpha and get/beta . In this case i want the method to process them parallely beacuse they have different path parameters.Is this possible with distributed locks.